# When are constraints implicitly AND'ed versus when must constraints be explicitly AND'ed?

Tags: alloy

This signature contains two fields, each holding an integer:

```
sig Test {
    a: Int,
    b: Int
}
```

This predicate contains a series of constraints:

```
pred Show (t: Test) {
    t.a = 0
    t.b = 1
}
```

Those constraints are implicitly AND'ed together. So, that predicate is equivalent to this predicate:

```
pred Show (t: Test) {
    t.a = 0 and
    t.b = 1
}
```

This assertion contains a series of constraints followed by an implication operator:

```
assert ImplicationTest {
    all t: Test {
        t.a = 0
        t.b = 1 => plus[t.a, t.b] = t.b
    }
}
```

But in this case the constraints are not implicitly AND'ed together. If I want them AND'ed together, I must explicitly AND them:

```
assert ImplicationTest {
    all t: Test {
        t.a = 0 and
        t.b = 1 => plus[t.a, t.b] = t.b
    }
}
```

Why is this? Why is it that sometimes a series of constraints are implicitly AND'ed together, whereas other times I must explicitly AND the constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the parser and as far as I can see it treats the right and left side of a newline/space as parenthesized expressions.

```
expr exprs -> expr and exprs
```

Thus:

```
t.a = 0  t.b = 1   t.c =2  => plus[t.a, t.b] = t.b
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(t.a = 0) and (t.b = 1 and ( t.c => plus[t.a, t.b] = t.b))
```

The following model seems to demonstrate that these expressions are equivalent:

```
sig Test {
    a: Int,
    b: Int,
    c: Int
}

pred simple( t: Test ) {
    t.a = 0 t.b = 1 t.c = 2 => plus[t.a, t.b] = t.b
}

pred full( t: Test ) {
    (t.a = 0) and  ((t.b = 1) and (t.c=2 => plus[t.a, t.b] = t.b))
}

assert Equivalent {
    all t : Test {
        simple[t] <=> full[t]
    }
}

check Equivalent for 10
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Peter Kriens!